# SQL Syntax Error Android

Tags: android, sql, syntax

I am getting an SQL syntax error but I'm not quite sure why. This is the error code I am obtaining;

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "GCSE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT foreign_word,english_meaning,correct FROM vocab_words WHERE name = AQA GCSE Spanish Higher
```

Any suggestions to fix this - I don't know what the error is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when the column's data type is string, its value should be wrapped with single quote.

```
SELECT foreign_word,english_meaning,correct 
FROM vocab_words 
WHERE name = 'AQA GCSE Spanish Higher'
```

Comment: Damn it - I keep making these mistakes. Thanks!